# How to print a Z-report on a fiscal printer?

Tags: vba, printing

I am new to fiscal printers. I have managed to send transactions to the fiscal printer (FP3530) using both Java and VBA, but now  I need to conclude by printing the Z-Report. Has anyone done this, Please help.

I tried the method for daily report as provided with an API but no luck.
I will be grateful to understand where the journals are read from as one method need it as a parameter, as in VBA code below.

```
    GET_JOURNAL(ReadAndErase As Boolean, FileName As String, ByRef CRC32 As     String, ByRef SHA1 As String) As Boolean
```

Trying to use it as follows:

```
Public Sub PrintZ_Report()
    On Error GoTo errorsave
    FP = New FP3530.CSFP3530
    FP.Init(1, 115200, 0, 0, 8)

    Dim fname As String
    Dim nClosure As Long
    Dim dbFM_Total As Double
    Dim dbTaxA As Double
    Dim dbTaxB As Double
    Dim dbTaxC As Double
    Dim dbTaxD As Double
    Dim dbTaxE As Double

    varBool = FP.GET_JOURNAL(True, fname, 1, 1)'Cannot figure out fname
    If Not varBool Then
        MsgBox("Error getting journal")

    End If
    varBool = FP.DAILY_REPORT(0, True, nClosure, dbFM_Total, dbTaxA, dbTaxB, dbTaxC, dbTaxD, dbTaxE)
    If Not varBool Then
        MsgBox("Error creating DAILY_REPORT")
        'Error handler goes here
    End If
    End
    Exit Sub
    errorsave:
       'MsgBox Err.Description
        Resume Next
End Sub
```

Comment: How is this Java related?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to put the java equivalent. But mainly, my struggle is not the PATH to get the journal

Comment: I have put the java here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33646235/how-to-print-a-z-report-on-a-fiscal-printer-java